# Is there any way we can use AWS Instance Scheduler for starting/stopping EC2 instances which have a huge process to start up the application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-instance-scheduler

We are trying to use AWS Instance Scheduler v1.4.2 our organization-wide for cost optimization. However, during implementation one case we are facing difficulty with is for EC2 instances in which a lot of setup needs to happen to start-up the application after we shut and restart them.

Is there any way we can overcome this issue and use instance scheduler for EC2 instances like these, too?

Comment: Have you tried a custom AMI that has at least some of the setup built into it?